# Playstation Network Card by email?

Tags: psn

Is there a way to buy a Playstation Network Card and get the code sent by email?

I don't want to wait for the snail mail to deliver a simple code that could be easily transferred by email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend these sites: [Maximus cards](http://www.maximuscards.com) and [ecodes247](http://www.ecodes247.com) . I purchased several cards from Maximus without a problem. Keep in mind that when you surpass a certain amount of credit purchased from them, they ask for more information such as a telephone number and things like that. The other one was recommended by a friend and I haven't tried them yet.

Comment: You might pay more than the actual price. The best thing to do is buy it in stores. A small move can be good sometimes :)